# Return and pass a callback in arrow function format

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

I wanna

1. return an arrow function and
2. pass an arrow function to another function.

Code:

```js
const NumberValue = {
  GREATER_THAN_0: i => i > 0,
  LESS_THAN_0: i => i < 0,
  EQUAL_TO_0: i => i == 0
};

function printStatistics(...a) {
    for (var key in NumberValue) {
        if (NumberValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + sum(NumberValue[key],a));
        }
    }
}

function sum(callback, ...a) {
    return a.filter(callback);
}

console.log(printStatistics(-5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1));
```

**I'm trying the following:**
I pass to `printStatistics(...a)` an int array then
I wanna print each key of the `NumberValue` object with an array of int that must to be filtered according to each arrow expression that are stored in the respective values of the `NumberValue` object.

I don't know what is not working. Whether the return of the arrow functions or to pass they to another function.

Expected results:

> GREATER_THAN_0 -> [5,4,3,2,1]
> LESS_THAN_0 -> [-5,-1]
> EQUAL_TO_0 -> [0]

But I am getting:

> GREATER_THAN_0 ->
> LESS_THAN_0 ->
> EQUAL_TO_0 ->
> undefined

**In resume**

So how can I return and pass an arrow function correctly?

Comment: `sum` should either just take `a` instead of `...a`, or you need to call `sum(NumberValue[key], ...a)`. Right now you accept rest parameters *twice*, so the second time you go from an array of integers into an array containing an array of integers.

Comment: Just remove the 3 dots before the `a` parameter in the `sum` function

Comment: @VLAZ Wow, every day I am learning a new thing in JavaScript! Many thanks dude!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The problem is that you use `...a` *twice*. This is [rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and it turns all the parameters into an array. However, since it's used two times, the first one converts the parameters to an array, the second time you just pass said array and it's wrapped into another array:

```js
console.log("result:", foo(1, 2, 3));

function foo(...a) { 
  console.log("`a` in foo:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3]
  return bar(a);
}

function bar(...a) {
  console.log("`a` in bar:", a); // a = [[1, 2, 3]] - array inside array
  return a;
}
```

## Solution

There are two ways to solve this:

### Don't use rest parameters

You can simply remove the rest parameter syntax from the second call and this will avoid wrapping the array into another array

```js
console.log("result:", foo(1, 2, 3));

function foo(...a) { 
  console.log("`a` in foo:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3]
  return bar(a);
}

function bar(a) { //no rest parameter syntax
  console.log("`a` in bar:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3] - single array
  return a;
}
```

```js
const NumberValue = {
  GREATER_THAN_0: i => i > 0,
  LESS_THAN_0: i => i < 0,
  EQUAL_TO_0: i => i == 0
};

function printStatistics(...a) {
    for (var key in NumberValue) {
        if (NumberValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + sum(NumberValue[key],a));
        }
    }
}

function sum(callback, a) {
    return a.filter(callback);
}

console.log(printStatistics(-5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1));
```

### Spread the array into the call

If you *want* to still be able to call the second function with variable amount of arguments, you can leave the rest parameter syntax but instead [use spread syntax to make the array into a list of arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_function_calls):

```js
console.log("result:", foo(1, 2, 3));

function foo(...a) { 
  console.log("`a` in foo:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3]
  return bar(a);
}

function bar(...a) {
  console.log("`a` in bar:", a); // a = [[1, 2, 3]] - array inside array
  return a;
}
```

```js
console.log("result:", foo(1, 2, 3));

function foo(...a) { 
  console.log("`a` in foo:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3]
  return bar(...a); //spread syntax
}

function bar(...a) { //rest syntax
  console.log("`a` in bar:", a); // a = [1, 2, 3] - single array
  return a;
}
```

```js
const NumberValue = {
  GREATER_THAN_0: i => i > 0,
  LESS_THAN_0: i => i < 0,
  EQUAL_TO_0: i => i == 0
};

function printStatistics(...a) {
    for (var key in NumberValue) {
        if (NumberValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + sum(NumberValue[key], ...a));
        }
    }
}

function sum(callback, ...a) {
    return a.filter(callback);
}

console.log(printStatistics(-5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to type insteed of "...a" "[...a] and give an array of numbers as arguments of printStatistics function